# Struts 1 text box not populating form value

Tags: java, forms, struts

I have a struts form with Address objects as attributes. I can populate the html form with these object but when the form is submitted the Address objects are null.

Code from jsp:

```
<bean:define id="AddressBean" name="FormObject" property="shippingAddress"/>
<html:text name="AddressBean" property="streetAddressLine" />
```

As I said the text box is being populated with the correct data but after submission the address object is null.

How can I get the address objects to not be null and be populated with the data from the text boxes?

Comment: Add the scope to bean tag

Comment: @MayurB It is finding the FormObject so adding scope shouldn't change anything.

Comment: After submitting where are you reading the same object.In action or in next jsp